# update tkinter canvas in separate classes

Tags: python, tkinter

Right now I have the code below in a land class to print a game board. There is a separate class that holds the games actions, so that every time something happens in the game this function is called. At this point the class builds a new canvas and destroys the old one over and over again every time. Is there a way to have it simply update the canvas instead of having to destory it.

```
def printBoard(self):
        master = Tk()

        w = Canvas(master, width=503, height=503)
        w.pack()
        for x, row in enumerate(self.a):
            for y, cell in enumerate(row):
                if self.a[x][y][1] == 'C':
                    w.create_rectangle([3 + 50 * y, 3 + 50 * x, 53 + 50 * y, 53 + 50 * x ], fill="black")
                    w.create_text(3 + 50 * y, 3 + 50 * x, anchor=NW, fill="white", text=self.a[x][y][0][1])
                else:
                    if self.a[x][y][0][0] == 'f':     
                        w.create_rectangle([3 + 50 * y, 3 + 50 * x, 53 + 50 * y, 53 + 50 * x ], fill="green")
                        w.create_text(3 + 50 * y, 3 + 50 * x, anchor=NW, fill="white", text=self.a[x][y][0][1])
                    elif self.a[x][y][0][0] == 'w':
                        w.create_rectangle([3 + 50 * y, 3 + 50 * x, 53 + 50 * y, 53 + 50 * x ], fill="blue")
                        w.create_text(3 + 50 * y, 3 + 50 * x, anchor=NW, fill="white", text=self.a[x][y][0][1])
                    elif self.a[x][y][0][0] == 'X':
                        w.create_rectangle([3 + 50 * y, 3 + 50 * x, 53 + 50 * y, 53 + 50 * x ], fill="brown")
                        w.create_text(3 + 50 * y, 3 + 50 * x, anchor=NW, fill="white", text=self.a[x][y][0][1])
                    elif self.a[x][y][0][0] == 's':
                        w.create_rectangle([3 + 50 * y, 3 + 50 * x, 53 + 50 * y, 53 + 50 * x ], fill="gray")
                        w.create_text(3 + 50 * y, 3 + 50 * x, anchor=NW, fill="white", text=self.a[x][y][0][1])
        master.after(1000, lambda: master.destroy())
        master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can store the IDs of the canvas items when you create them, so they can be used to update their positions with the [`coords`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.coords-method) method and [`itemconfig`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemconfig-method) to change the options (like the fill color).

```
# Create
self.ids[x][y] = w.create_rectangle([3 + 50 * y, ...)

# Update
fillcolors = {'f':'green', 'w':'blue', 'X':'brown', 's':'gray'}
fill = "black" if self.a[x][y][1] == 'C' else fillcolors[self.a[x][y][0][0]]
w.coords(self.ids[x][y], [3 + 50 * y, ...)
w.itemconfig(self.ids[x][y], fill=fill)
```

Note that there is a lot of duplicated code, so you can use an auxiliar dictionary where you have the colors already mapped, and then avoid the nested conditionals.

Comment: Does itemconfig need to be called for every, rectangle in the canvas, is there a way in the update function to build a new canvas and just sort of swap the two?

Comment: @EasilyBaffled No, each canvas has its own items, so you have to update the existing one. Creating a new canvas and all its items has much worse performance than calling coords and itemconfig for every ID.

Comment: ok so I just want to get it strait I have to create an id for very rectangle so it will end up something like self.ids[0][2] = w.create_rectangle([3 + 50 * y, ...), self.ids[0][2] = w.create_rectangle([3 + 50 * y, ...) and so on. Obviously these should all be saved. then for update i have to go through each one and update those that need to be updated.

Comment: @EasilyBaffled Yes, and the same for the text items. Good luck!